# C++ and QT-creator error: undefined reference to `empleado::~empleado()'

Tags: c++, qt

Why /home/jeison/Dropbox/PROGRAMACION/Jeison/Lab5/directorio.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `empleado::~empleado()'

Thnaks

Empleado.hpp, it's class empleado, with all your information

```
    #ifndef _EMPLEADO_HPP
#define _EMPLEADO_HPP
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::string;

class empleado{
    private:
        string identificacion;
        string tipo_identificacion;
        string nombres_apellidos;
        string fecha_nacimiento;
        string telefono_fijo;
        string telefono_celular;
        string email;
    public:
        empleado();
        empleado(string id, string tipo_id, string nom_ape, string fecha, string tel_fijo, string tel_celular, string correo);
       ~empleado();

        string get_identificacion();
        void set_identificacion(string id);

        string get_tipo_identificacion();
        void set_tipo_identificacion(string tipo_id);

        string get_nombres_apellidos();
        void set_nombres_apellidos(string nom_ape);

        string get_fecha_nacimiento();
        void set_fecha_nacimiento(string fecha);

        string get_telefono_fijo();
        void set_telefono_fijo(string tel_fijo);

        string get_telefono_celular();
        void set_telefono_celular(string tel_celular);

        string get_email();
        void set_email(string correo);

    };
#endif
```

Empleado.cpp it's class empleado, with all your information

```
#include "empleado.hpp"

empleado::empleado(){}
empleado::empleado(string id, string tipo_id, string nom_ape, string fecha, string tel_fijo, string tel_celular, string correo){
    this -> identificacion = id; 
    this -> tipo_identificacion = tipo_id;
    this -> nombres_apellidos = nom_ape;
    this -> fecha_nacimiento = fecha;
    this -> telefono_fijo = tel_fijo;
    this -> telefono_celular = tel_celular;
    this -> email = correo;
    }
empleado::~empleado(){}

    string empleado::get_identificacion() {return identificacion;}
    void empleado::set_identificacion(string id) {this -> identificacion = id;}

    string empleado::get_tipo_identificacion() {return tipo_identificacion;}
    void empleado::set_tipo_identificacion(string tipo_id) {this -> tipo_identificacion = tipo_id;}

    string empleado::get_nombres_apellidos() {return nombres_apellidos;}
    void empleado::set_nombres_apellidos(string nom_ape) {this -> nombres_apellidos = nom_ape;}

    string empleado::get_fecha_nacimiento() {return fecha_nacimiento;}
    void empleado::set_fecha_nacimiento(string fecha) {this -> fecha_nacimiento = fecha;}

    string empleado::get_telefono_fijo() {return telefono_fijo;}
    void empleado::set_telefono_fijo(string tel_fijo) {this -> telefono_fijo = tel_fijo;}

    string empleado::get_telefono_celular() {return telefono_celular;}
    void empleado::set_telefono_celular(string tel_celular) {this -> telefono_celular = tel_celular;}

    string empleado::get_email() {return email;}
    void empleado::set_email(string correo) {this -> email = correo;}
```

.pro

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-11-16T23:17:16
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

TARGET = Lab5
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        login.cpp \
    menu.cpp \
    validacion.cpp \
    editarestudiantes.cpp \
    profesor.cpp \
    estudiante.cpp \
    administrativo.cpp \
    empleado.cpp \
    directorio.cpp

HEADERS  += login.hpp \
    menu.hpp \
    validacion.hpp \
    editarestudiantes.hpp \
    profesor.hpp \
    estudiante.hpp \
    empleado.hpp \
    administrativo.hpp \
    directorio.hpp

FORMS    += login.ui \
    menu.ui \
    editarestudiantes.ui

RESOURCES +=
```

Comment: This is not an answer, but you don't need a user defined destructor for that class, so you could just remove it.

Comment: thanks, already solve :)